# document.title and spaces in a string

Tags: javascript, html, breadcrumbs

I'm using a breadcrumbs.js file.

```
function breadcrumbs(){
sURL = new String;
bits = new Object;
var x = 0;
var stop = 0;
var output = "";
sURL = location.href;
sURL = sURL.slice(8,sURL.length);
chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length)
while(!stop){
    chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
    if (chunkStart != -1){
        bits[x] = sURL.slice(0,chunkStart)
        sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length);
    }else{
        stop = 1;
    }
    x++;
}
for(var i in bits){
    output += "<a href=\"";
    for(y=1;y<x-i;y++){
        output += "../";
    }
    output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i] + "<a/a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; ";
}
document.write(output + document.title);
}
```

What it does is to traverse the folder structure and build it as a set of breadcrumbs. So for example:

```
/root
+ design-library
---+ foo
--------+ bar
------------+ baz name with space
```

And this would return as:

```
design-library | foo | bar | baz%20name%20with%20space | filename
```

How can I maintain the space in the file folder name, but return as:

```
design-library | foo | bar | baz name with space | filename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `decodeURIComponent(str)`, which converts `%xx` values back into single characters.